# How to make new window get the focus when Emacs in full-screen mode in Xfce4?

Tags: xfce, focus

I'm using the Xfce4 desktop environment on top of Linux Mint 18.1. When using Emacs in full-screen mode, I want to open a new application via the `xfce whisker menu`, but the new application is always hidden under the full-screen Emacs.

How can I make that new window gain the focus instead of full-screen Emacs?

Comment: Is the "New Window Focus" box checked in Settings -> Window Manager -> Focus?

Comment: @Munir: yes, it is checked. This problem happens to only the full-screen mode of Emacs, or other applications like Firefox, Google Chrome.

Comment: Found another option that might cause this. In Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Focus, uncheck "Activate focus stealing prevention". If it still doesn't work, maybe it's an Emacs thing. I don't use emacs so can't help much there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. Do you want to create an answer so that I can upvote and accept it? :-D

Comment: Added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Window Manager -> Focus and check the box that says "New Window Focus"

Also, go to Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Focus and uncheck the box that says "Activate focus stealing prevention"